# Join tables to display null if right side table doesnt have data

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, where-clause

I have a feedback_ques, feedback_ans table as follows:

```
feedback_ques
 
id  question                created_date    created_by delete_date
1   How was the training    16-SEP-20       900         null
2   facility?               16-SEP-20       900         null    
3   Dept?                   16-SEP-20       902         null
4   Infrastructure          16-SEP-20       900         16-SEP-20

feedback_ans

ques_id member_id   answers created_date    created_by
1       10          good    16-SEP-20       891
2       10          good    16-SEP-20       891
3       10          poor    16-SEP-20       891
4       10          good    16-SEP-20       891
```

I want to join the tables as follows:

```
select q.id as id, a.member_id as memberId, q.question as Ques, a.answers as Ans
from feedback_ques q, feedback_ans a
where q.id = a.ques_id(+) 
and a.member_id = 10
and q.DELETE_DATE IS NULL;
```

This gives me all the fields. I want the query to return null for answers if they arent found in the answers table.
For example member_id 20 doesnt have answers, so i would want the table to display null values as below for this query.

```
select q.id as id, a.member_id as memberId, q.question as Ques, a.answers as Ans
from feedback_ques q, feedback_ans a
where q.id = a.ques_id(+) 
and a.member_id = 20
and q.DELETE_DATE IS NULL;

ID  memberId    Ques                    ans
1   20          How was the training    null
2   20          facility?               null
3   20          Dept?                   null
4   20          Infrastructure          null
```

Updated:
As suggested im using leftOuter join as follows:

```
select q.id as id, a.member_id as memberId, q.question as Ques, a.answers as Ans
from feedback_ques q
left join feedback_ans a on a.ques_id = q.id and a.member_id = 20
and q.delete_date is null;
```

But this query is not working when delete_date is !=null. That row is still returned by the query. From above quest 4 should not be returned since delete_date != null.
Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These old-shool, implicit joins, make it uneasy to express what you want. Here, the condition `a.member_id = 20` in the where clause filters out unmatched rows.

This is just one of the reasons while explicit, standard joins should always be used. Consider a `left join`, where all conditions on the left table are placed in the `on` clause:

```
select q.id as id, a.member_id as memberId, q.question as Ques, a.answers as Ans
from feedback_ques q
left join feedback_ans a on a.ques_id = q.id and a.member_id = 20
where q.delete_date is null;
```

Comment: have another question. Say for example q.delete_date != null, this left outer join still gets that row.

Comment: @JNPW: `q.delete_date IS NOT NULL`

Comment: sorry i wasnt clear. I am not asking how to use != null. If you see my updated question and the table values, question 4 shouldnot be pulled when feedback answer exists but delete date is not null

Comment: @JNPW: then that condition should to the `where` clause. I edited my answer.